# Generic extending or generic that extends

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I find this approach valid:

```
public class Test<T extends Number>{
```

as well as

```
public class Test<T> extends Number{
```

is there any good practice that am missing, since both approaches will give me the same result, only that the 2nd one forces me to implement the abstract methods.

```
public int intValue() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}


public long longValue() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}


public float floatValue() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}


public double doubleValue() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

thanks

Comment: If you have `Test<T extends Number>` it means that your class contains a variable that is a number of type T, where as if you have `Test<T> extends Number` the type var is useless, and your `Test` class is of type `Number`

Comment: This question is odd.  You don't seem to use T anywhere, and as Ash pointed out above, the semantics of the two alternatives are hugely different.  Can you explain maybe more about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I find this approach valid... as well as...

Well, they're both valid Java.

> since both approaches will give me the same result

No, they mean very different things.

Let's call the classes implementing the two approaches `Test1` and `Test2`:

```
class Test1<T extends Number> { ... }
class Test2<T> extends Number { ... }

Test1<Integer> a1 = new Test1<>();  // OK.
Test2<Integer> a2 = new Test2<>();  // OK.

Test1<Object> b1 = new Test1<>();   // Compiler error: Object not in bounds.
Test2<Object> b2 = new Test2<>();   // OK - T isn't bounded.

Number c1 = new Test1<Integer>();   // Compiler error: a Test1 isn't a Number.
Number c2 = new Test2<Integer>();   // OK.
```

So, the two classes aren't equivalent.

The one you should choose depends upon what you're trying to achieve.